# Compile Error With BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am wanting to pass an additional parameter to my `DoWork` method, but am getting a compile error of `No overload for 'backgroundWorker1_DoWork' matches delegate 'System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler'`

This is my syntax, what should I do to fix this?

```
namespace Testing
{
public partial class Form1 : Form1
{
    public static string[] employeeName;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
    }
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(employeeName);
    }
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e, string[] employeeName)
    {
        //Just for example sake
        for (int q = employeeName.GetLowerBound(0); q <= employeeName.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
        {
          MessageBox.Show(employeeName[q];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `string[] employeeName` parameter to your even handler, it should only have first two parameters

Comment: @Habib I'll update my code as I need to use that variable in my DoWork procedure

Comment: @BigPimpin: it doesn't work like this. You get the argument from e.Argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DoWorkEventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) has the following definition :

```
public delegate void DoWorkEventHandler(
    Object sender,
    DoWorkEventArgs e
)
```

You cannot add a third argument. The object you want to get is in `DoWorkEventArgs.Argument` property.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form1
{
    public static string[] employeeName;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
    }
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(employeeName);
    }
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] employeeName = (string[])e.Argument;
        //Just for example sake
        for (int q = employeeName.GetLowerBound(0); q <= employeeName.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
        {
          MessageBox.Show(employeeName[q];
        }
    }
}
```